# Javascript arrays undefined values

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I have some code that produces undefined values in an array making no sense.

here is the code:

```
gcc_py = 8;
gcc_pyd = 12;
var aci = 360/gcc_pyd;
var parcalar = new Array();
var renkler = new Array();

for(var i = 0;i<gcc_pyd;i++){   
    parcalar.push(aci);
    renkler.push('#000');
}

console.log(parcalar);
console.log(renkler);
```

console.log(parcalar) outputs this:

> [
>   Object
>   , 
>   Object
>   , 
>   Object
>   , 
>   Object
>   , 
>   Object
>   , 
>   Object
>   , 
>   Object
>   , 
>   Object
>   , 
>   Object
>   , 
>   Object
>   , undefined × 2]

do you have any idea for the undefined values in the array?

Comment: It outputs `[30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]` for me.

Comment: I put that to the Firefox Web console and it prints `[30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]` and `["#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000"]`.

Comment: Also, please change  new Array(); to [] it's considered better practice

Comment: I got valid results as well. What are you testing this in?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/HjVDp/

Comment: thanks for the comments, i'm running this on google chrome

Comment: What happens when you initialize it with `[]` versus `new Array();`? Using `[]` is safer so I would recommend that. It's possible that `Array` might have been overridden by something else. Are you using any third-party libraries?

Comment: @exculuber: Is the the *exact* code you're running?

Comment: yes it is the exact code and i have tried `[]` but nothing is changed how can i check whether the other plugins have been changed the prototype of array

Comment: @exculuber: What are the contents of the Objects you're seeing in the console?

Comment: @Rocket Object
order: 6
value: 30
valueOf: function () { return this.value; }
__proto__: Object

Comment: @exculuber You clearly have some more code beyond what is posted here. You should show us the entire code if you need help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are changing the arrays afterwards. The console will reflect these changes, e.g. then showing objects instead of numbers and strings. Also, when deleting properties from an array (via `delete`, see [Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500606/1048572)), they will still show up as initialised but empty (see [What is "undefined x 1" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10683773/1048572)).

Comment: yes, after these lines there is a function call in which these arrays are passed. The function changes the array. Thank you for the answer. Do you have further information about this concept may be a documentation, link, etc?

Comment: documentation about what? For [console](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) you'll find http://getfirebug.com/logging or http://patik.com/blog/complete-cross-browser-console-log/ helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The output for me shows

```
[30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]

["#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000"]
```

Maybe you've added some .prototype stuff to Array somewhere else in the code?

Comment: I'm using raphael.js and its plugin piechart.js

Answer (score 0):

When I run the same configuration:

```
<script>
  var gcc_py = 8;
  var gcc_pyd = 12;
  var aci = 360 / gcc_pyd;
  var parcalar = new Array();
  var renkler = new Array();

  for(var i = 0; i < gcc_pyd; i++){
      parcalar.push(aci);
      renkler.push('#000');
  }

  console.log(parcalar);
  console.log(renkler);
</script>
```

I get:

```
[30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]
["#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000"]
```

not sure what you're seeing.

Comment: My console outputs it as an array of objects do you have any idea for that?