# What is the difference between [undefined] and [,]?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “undefined x 1” in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683773/what-is-undefined-x-1-in-javascript)

In Chrome 21, feeding `[,]` to the console outputs

> [undefined x 1]

and feeding `[undefined]` outputs

> [undefined]

What is the difference between `[undefined]` and `[undefined x 1]`?

What is the notation `[undefined x 1]`?

Comment: I believe, you need to read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683773/what-is-undefined-x-1-in-javascript)

Comment: Console output is not data, and it's not *(necessarily)* JavaScript notation or syntax. It's a visual representation of data as the console developers decided it should look. Sometimes it's helpful, sometimes it can be confusing or misleading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[,]` is a [sparse array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1510778/1048572). It has a length of `1`, but no values (`0 in [,] === false`). It can also be written as `new Array(1)`.

`[undefined]` is an array of length `1` with the value `undefined` at index `0`.

When accessing the property "`0`", both will return `undefined` - the first because that property is not defined, the second because the value is "undefined". However, the arrays are different, and so is their [output in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683773/what-is-undefined-x-1-in-javascript).

Answer (score 5):

`[,]` creates an array with length of 1 and no indices.

`[undefined]` creates an array with length of 1 with `undefined` value at index `0`.

Chrome's `undefined × x` is for sparse arrays that don't have sequential indices:

```
var a = [];

a[8] = void 0; //set the 8th index to undefined, this will make the array's length to be 9 as specified. The array is sparse
console.log(a) //Logs undefined × 8, undefined, which means there are 8 missing indices and then a value `undefined`
```

If you were to use `.forEach` on a sparse array, it skips the indices that don't exist.

```
a.forEach(function() {
    console.log(true); //Only logs one true even though the array's length is 9
});
```

Where as if you do a normal `.length` based loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    console.log(true); //will of course log 9 times because it's only .length based
}
```

There is a gotcha if you expect `.forEach` to behave the same as non-standard implementations.

```
new Array(50).forEach( function() {
    //Not called, the array doesn't have any indices
});

$.each( new Array(50), function() {
    //Typical custom implementation calls this 50 times
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats odd `[]` outputs just `[]` again for me on Chrome 21.

Anyway `[a, b, c, ...]` is the array notation of Javascript so you are basically defining an array with no values.

However an ending `,` is acceptable to make array generation easier. So what Chrome is telling you is there is one undefined value in the array. See code for examples.

```
[,,]
> [undefined x2]
[1,2,]
> [1, 2]
[1,2,,]
> [1, 2, undefined × 1]
[1,2,,,]
> [1, 2, undefined × 2]
[1,2,,3,4,,,6]
> [1, 2, undefined × 1, 3, 4, undefined × 2, 6]
```

Comment: The values are undefined in that they do not exist; they are not set to `undefined`. And JavaScript can handle such arrays perfectly fine.

Comment: Which is the definition of undefined. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is the wording which is not very accurate. I've edited if you don't mind.

Comment: The problem is that describing something that is not will always have many possible points of view to look at the text... I added an additional example that should make it very clear what I meant ;)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it's just a shorthand way to display the repeated 'undefined' values. eg:

```
> [,,,]
  [ undefined x 3 ]
```

But `[]` is not the same as `[undefined]` at all. I'd double check that if I were you.

Comment: Please reread my question. I'm asking about `[,]`, not `[]`.

Comment: Explanation of pimvdb's edit: http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.4, "If an element is elided at the end of an array, that element does not contribute to the length of the Array."

Comment: @Randomblue well yeah, since you edited it.. :-\

Comment: @nickf: The title (correct) was not edited. And the question with `[,]` replaced by `[]` doesn't really make sense.