# Strange ES6 Array.every behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
[,'a'].every(x => x==='a') 
> True
```

returns **True**, although the first item is 'undefined' and therefore should be **False?**

```
[,'a'].map(x => x) 
> [undefined × 1, "a"]
```

Comment: [You should read the docs for `Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The builtin array methods ignore non-existing properties on [sparse arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11809006/1048572). The first item is not `undefined`, there is no property in index `0` at all. You can try

```
[,'a'].every(x => x==='a') 
> true
[undefined,'a'].every(x => x==='a') 
> false
```

Comment: Proof that is a sparse array: `Object.keys([,'a'])` returns `["1"]`, and not `["0","1"]`.

Answer (score -3):

Since undefined is a typeof, use == (twice) instead of three times. It returns true because x is empty and therefore the typeof undefined matches undefined (since you use = three times)

Comment: It's the same True

Comment: Where does `typeof` come into play here?