# Undefined values when trying to create a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a multi-dimensional array.

My assumption that the following structure `stuff['mykey1']['mykey2']['mykey3']` can be interpreted as `stuff` is an array of two-dimensional arrays. And `stuff['mykey1']` will return me a two dimensional array with following keys `['mykey2']['mykey3']`

I try to create this structure like so:

```
var stuff = null;

if(stuff === null) 
{
    stuff = []; // stuff is []
}

if(stuff[userId] === undefined)
{
    stuff[userId] = [];  // stuff is [undefined, undefined, undefined, 888087 more...]
}

if(stuff[userId][objectId] === undefined)
{
    stuff[userId][objectId] = [];
}
```

However, when I look at stuff array as I step through, I see that after `stuff[userId] = []`; stuff array is `[undefined, undefined, undefined, 888087 more...]`

I'm expecting [888087, []]

Where do the undefined values come from?

Comment: Are you perhaps doing `Array(888087)` somewhere?

Comment: When you do `stuff[888087] = []` you're saying `stuff` is an array with a `length` of at least 888088. Are you sure that's what you want? Don't you want objects instead of arrays?

Comment: @bfavaretto: True, I forgot about the auto-sizing of arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where do the undefined values come from?

You are using Arrays, not objects. If you add a numerical property on an Array object, it's `length` will be updated and the other indices stay unitialized ([sparse array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1510778/1048572)), but are displayed as `undefined` (see [What is "undefined x 1" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10683773/1048572)).

Instead, use normal objects, where numerical properties have no special behavior:

```
var stuff = null;

if(stuff === null) 
{
    stuff = {}; // stuff is an empty object
}

if(stuff[userId] === undefined)
{
    stuff[userId] = {};  // stuff is now enriched with one property
}

if(stuff[userId][objectId] === undefined)
{
    stuff[userId][objectId] = {}; // or maybe you really want an array here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of usage of arrays. The length of the remainin elements is made undefined. 
For example if a(1) is specified,  a(0) will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create **associative arrays**, and in JavaScript this is done with... objects, not arrays!

So at each step you need to use {} instead of [] to create the next level. And you need to use a for...in loop to iterate through the keys.

For more details, search the Web for JavaScript associative arrays". For example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

The question is long answered, but I want to chip in with this shorthand, that really makes it more compact and readable:

```
stuff = stuff || {};

// if stuff is already defined, just leave it be. If not (||), define it as object

stuff[userId] = stuff[userId] || {};

// if stuff[userId] is already defined, define it as self (let it be unchanged). If not defined ( the || -signs ), define it as object.

stuff[userId][objectId] = stuff[userId][objectId] || {};

// and so on :)
```