# JavaScript 'in' operator for `undefined` elements in Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please consider the following snippet of code:

```
> a = [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, 3]
  [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, 3]
> b = [1,,,,3]
  [1, undefined × 3, 3]
> 1 in a
  true
> 1 in b
  false
```

Am I missing something? It seems to be that, depending on how I define `undefined` elements in an array, the `in` operator behaves differently.

Comment: See also [What is “`[undefined x 1]`” in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10683773/1048572)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Arrays are nothing but normal JavaScript objects, with some specialization. Quoting from [Array Objects section of ECMA 5.1 Specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4)

> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names. A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an *array index* if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>−1.

So, *array indices are nothing but properties of array objects*. Now, lets see about missing elements in an Array.

Quoting from the [ECMA 5.1 Standard Specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.4),

> Array elements may be elided at the beginning, middle or end of the
>   element list. Whenever a comma in the element list is not preceded by
>   an AssignmentExpression (i.e., a comma at the beginning or after
>   another comma), the missing array element contributes to the length of
>   the Array and increases the index of subsequent elements. Elided array
>   elements are not defined. If an element is elided at the end of an
>   array, that element does not contribute to the length of the Array.

So, when you say

```
b = [1,,,,3];
```

except the elements 1 and 3, all others are treated as missing elements in the array. Now elements `1` and `3` correspond to the properties `0` and `4` (Array indices start with `0` in JavaScript).

You can check that like this

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b));
# [ '0', '4', 'length' ]
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a));
# [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'length' ]
```

Only the indices `0` and `4` are in `b`. You might be wondering why `a` has the properties from `0` to `4`, though the values are `undefined`. Because, the elements at indices 1, 2 and 3 **are defined to be [`undefined`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.1)**, where as in `b`, we don't know what those values are. That is why they are not allocated to a property (index).

Now, you are checking if `1` is in `b`, with `in` operator. Quoting from [`in` operator MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in#Summary),

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.

So, you are basically checking if `1` is one of the properties of `b`, which is not. That is why `'1'` in `b` returns `false`.

### Note:

If you wanted to know if `1` is in the Array or not, you should use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), like this

```
console.log(a.indexOf(1));
# 0
console.log(b.indexOf(1));
# 0
console.log(b.indexOf(5));
# -1
```

`Array.prototype.indexOf` returns `-1` if the element being searched is not there in the Array. So, you might want to do something like this

```
console.log(a.indexOf(1) !== -1);
# true
console.log(b.indexOf(1) !== -1);
# true
console.log(a.indexOf(5) !== -1);
# false
```

Comment: I think your **Note** is the most important part. The OP seems to be looking for **values**, but is actually searching for **keys**, by using the wrong thing (`in` operator, not `[].indexOf`)...maybe not though

Comment: Most important part to me seems to be the concept of "defined to be `undefined`" - a lot of people seem to miss this distinction.

Comment: What @NiettheDarkAbsol said, and in my words - the difference between defined, undefined and undeclared. In the `,,,` case the element at position 1 is treated as if it is not declared. There is no property with that name.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, a[1] is defined, but is set to `undefined`, therefore `1 in a == true`. By contrast, b[1] is not set at all, therefore `1 in b == false`. This is why some people say that `undefined` is weird.

To check whether an array `a` has the *value* 1, use `a.indexOf(1) != -1`.

To check whether the `a[1]` is defined, use `a.hasOwnProperty("1")` (`1 in a` is subtly different, and is probably not actually what you want, because it can be true if `1` is defined in `a`'s prototype but not in `a` itself).

To set `a[1]` to `undefined`, use `a[1] = undefined`.

To make a `a[1]` stop being defined, use `delete a[1]`.

Answer (score -3):

```
//-1 means not in the list
//['a','b','c'].indexOf('a') is return index if not find in the list then it give -1.

if(['a','b','c'].indexOf('d') == -1)
{
    console.log('yes it -1')
}
```