# Pushing unique numbers within a range to an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I am trying to insert numbers from 1 to 15 into an array. 
And here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button id="myBtn" value="HELLO">HELLO</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
            var num = null;
            btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var questions = new Array();
                num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14 + 2);
                questions.push(num);

                for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
                    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14 + 2);
                    if (questions.indexOf(num) !== -1) {
                        alert(num + " Exists in array. So not pushing it");
                    } else {
                        alert(num + " is not found. So pushing it");
                        questions.push(num);
                    }
                    console.log(questions);
                }
                alert(questions);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you run this with the console open. You will notice that though a number is not in the array the `in` operator still discards the number without pushing. Can I know why and how to correct this?

And also is there any better way to insert x number of numbers in random order each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `in` operator with Arrays. What you should have done is

```
if (questions.indexOf(num) !== -1) {
```

When you use `in` with an Array, it will not check the values but the indices of the Array. That is why your code fails.

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22448440/1903116) of mine to know more about, why you should not use `in` operator with Arrays.

The best way to generate N unique random numbers is to, generate the list of numbers and then shuffle them, like this

```
function getRandomNumbers() {
    var rand, index = 0,
        array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

    array.forEach(function(value) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ++index);
        array[index - 1] = array[rand];
        array[rand] = value;
    });

    return array;
}

console.log(getRandomNumbers());
```

This is adopted from the `_.shuffle` function of Underscore.js library, which shuffles the list of data with [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm.

Comment: Yeah ok got it. Why shouldnt I use that? It works perfectly with lists in python. OK Is there any other way to insert 15 numbers to an array that are in unique order each time?

Comment: @user3283104 Regarding the `why` part, please check the linked question in my answer. I have explained extensively.

Comment: @user3283104: Python and JavaScript are different languages, and `in` works differently in Python.

Comment: @FelixKling Look at the last part of my question. Any answers for that?

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks I almost did something similar to this but was a bit buggy. Thanks for this. If you agree I will let you know for what I was using this.

Comment: @user3283104 If it is not much of a secret, I am all ears :)

Comment: @thefourtheye Ok will show it. Give me a week or two to complete it. :)

Answer (score 1):

the `in` operator works on [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), so you're really checking to see if your array has an *index*, not a value.