# How does JavaScript's forEach loop decide to skip or iterate through "undefined" and "null" elements in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I know that `forEach` method will iterate through an array object and will skip all array elements which are either `null` or `undefined`. I've an example below:

```
var a = [1,2,3,,5,6];
var b = [1,2,3,undefined,5,6];

var fn = function(arr){
    arr.forEach(function(currentValue, index, array){
      console.log(currentValue);
    });
};  

fn(a); //Prints on console (separated by newline): 1 2 3 5 6
fn(b); //Prints on console (separated by newline): 1 2 3 undefined 5 6
```

In above example,

- when `fn(a)` is executed, the `forEach` loop ignores the 4th element `a[3]` which is undefined.
- But, when `fn(b)` is executed, the `forEach` loop iterates through the 4th element `b[3]` which is also undefined.

What is the difference between `a[3]` and `b[3]` here? Why `forEach` loop didn't skip `b[3]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript 'in' operator for \`undefined\` elements in Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448330/javascript-in-operator-for-undefined-elements-in-arrays)

Comment: The premise is just wrong: forEach won't skip elements that are null or undefined. It skips elements that don't exist at all.

Comment: @JJJ is right. Try `[null, , undefined].forEach(console.log)`. It prints `null`, skips the index with no value, then prints `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specifications of [ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4), missing array items are *elided*.

> Whenever a comma in the element list is not preceded by an AssignmentExpression (i.e., a comma at the beginning or after another comma), the missing array element contributes to the length of the Array and increases the index of subsequent elements. Elided array elements are not defined.

Since they are undefined, behaviour is unpredictable and there is no definition as to whether these should be treated as normal array items like `undefined`. I suspect that in some browsers, undefined may be returned, but this doesn't appear to be the case in Chrome. Here's what your first example of `[1, 2, 3,, 5, 6]` evaluates to:

```
[1, 2, 3, undefined × 1, 5, 6]
```

However, `[1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6]` just evaluates to:

```
[1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6]
```

As we can see, these are subtly different, so the behaviour is not the same even though they look superficially similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you print the arrays in the console you will get:

```
var a = [1,2,3,,5,6];
var b = [1,2,3,undefined,5,6];
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Console

```
    >[1, 2, 3, 4: 5, 5: 6]
    >
    0:1
    1:2
    2:3
    4:5
    5:6
    length:6


    >[1, 2, 3,undefined, 5,6]
    >
    0:1
    1:2
    2:3
    3:undefined
    4:5
    5:6
    length:6
```

So there are not element in index 3.