# What's the difference between empty items in a JavaScript array and undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

Consider the following JavaScript code (in a node REPL):

```
> let a = new Array(10)
undefined
> a
[ <10 empty items> ]
> a.map(e => 1)
[ <10 empty items> ]
> let b = new Array(10).fill(undefined)
undefined
> b
[ undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined ]
> b.map(e => 1)
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
>
```

When I create an empty array, I'll get 'empty items' which seem to behave differently from `undefined`. Can someone explain what is the difference?

Comment: in the first case probably only length is set.

Comment: An empty slot will not set the "index-key" on your Array object, thus some methods won't go there.

Comment: @Mihai your edit doesn't reflect the original question's title nor its body.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When I create an empty array, I'll get 'empty items' which seem to
>   behave differently from undefined. Can someone explain what is the
>   difference?

That's because `Array(10)` doesn't populate the array. But it just set the **length** property to `10` .So, the array created using `Array` constructor is simply an object with a length property, but with no items populated.

Comment: not sure this is correct. Can't provide a proof from the ECMA spec, but everything must have a value. That's the whole point of the `undefined` value in JS, that it fills the void if necessary. It's more like an environment specific feature to differentiate between cases when the value was explicitly provided and happened to be `undefined` and when it was provided by the engine.

Comment: @d.k Any attempt to *access* an empty slot on the Array object will return `undefined`, but this answer doesn't seem to be incorrect; as Mihai states, the array is *not* actually populated by this operation. If you run `new console.info(Array(700 * 1024 ** 2))`, it will complete in an instant, much less time than would be required to touch 5.8 GB of RAM.

Comment: Even though you argue “everything *must* have a value”, there is still a programmatically detectable difference between **(a)** an Array slot that contains `null`, **(b)** an Array slot that contains `undefined`, and **(c)** an Empty Array slot. The OP is asking what is the \*difference\* between an Empty slot and one which contains `undefined`. The fact that they both produce `undefined` when accessed is not a difference; it is a \*similarity\*.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude thank you, I tend to agree now. Especially the **similarity** point. Also what helped me to see the difference between an array with length 10 and an array with length 10 with populated indices: `console.log(someIndex in myArray);` if an something is present at index, even if it's an `undefined`, then the log shows `true`. If something is not present at index, even if it's below the length of the array — the log shows false.

Answer (score 11):

That's because `undefined` is a value, while when you create an array for example like this:

```
var array = [];
array.length = 10;
console.log(array);
>(10) [empty × 10] // in google chrome
```

10 empty slots are created.
The empty slot is different from the undefined value, and the most important difference is that the empty slot is not Enumerable.

```
var mappedArray = array.map(x => 1);
console.log(mappedArray);
>(10) [empty × 10] // in google chrome
```

Since `map` function enumerates the values in the orriginal array and returns the array of the same length, it has no effect on the array of 10 empty slots.

Note that empty slots are named differently in different browsers.

Comment: The formal name is *Ellision* http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-initializer