# Difference between "empty' and "undefined" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

According to ECMAScript there are `null` and `undefined` datatypes apart from others.
But recently I got to see something called `empty`. Let's regenerate it first (I'll go from basic):

`let a = new Array()`     *//Returns `[]` length=0*

`let b = new Array(3)`    *//Returns `[empty*3]` length=3*

`let c = new Array(3).fill()` *//Return `[undefined,undefined,undefined]` length=3*

Now, what? 
See all the elements defined are undefined, which they should be

- `a[0]=undefined`
- `b[0]=undefined`
- `c[0]=undefined`

Main thing: 
If suppose add an element into `c` at position 5 i.e `a[5]=4`
then `c` will be `[undefined,undefined,undefined,empty,4]`

What is this empty thing in between? And if everything is same what is the difference in starting initialization of `b` and `c` ( I'm talking about `[empty*3]` & `[undefined,undefined,undefined]`).

The Answer suggested [here]: [What's the difference between empty items in a JavaScrip array and undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326047/whats-the-difference-between-empty-items-in-a-javascrip-array-and-undefined) Doesn't explains the properly about what exactly it is. Yes it can't be `undefined` as `undefined` is a value but what about `null` and if not `null` why empty is not a data-type?

Comment: Node.js is largely just V8 which makes it very similar to Chrome in terms of pure JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, Node.js behaves in a similar fashion. The browser console I'm talking about is spidermonkey. Anyway results are same.

Comment: `empty` is not actually a "thing" in JavaScript. The reason your console spits out `empty` is because that it its attempt to clearly represent a [sparse array](http://2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html). JS consoles are not bound by any standard, so different consoles may represent these holes in the array differently

Comment: For example, the [repl.it](https://repl.it/@ugam44/IndelibleSorrowfulVariety) console returns `[ undefined, undefined, undefined, <1 empty item>, 4 ]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arrays are objects. That means that your array

```
  [undefined,undefined,undefined,empty,4]
```

could be written as such an object:

```
 {
  0: undefined,
  1: undefined,
  2: undefined,
  // 3 doesnt exist at all
  4: 4,
  length: 5,
 }
```

So `undefined` is actually a slot that exists and holds a value while `3` is not even a key-value pair. As accessing a non existing key results in `undefined` there is no real world difference:

```
    array[2] // undefined
    array[3] // undefined
```

But iterating over an array with `map` and others will skip empty ones, so then you should use `.fill` before iterating.

The only way to detect a difference is to check if the key exists:

```
  2 in array // true
  3 in array // false
```

To turn `empty` to `undefined` you could set the key:

```
  array[3] = undefined;
```

and to turn `undefined` into `empty` you have to remove the key:

```
  delete array[3]
```

however that rarely matters.

Answer (score 0):

`empty` is not a type. It is just a way of describing that there is nothing there. It isn't `undefined` or `null`. It is the complete lack of a value. You'll only see that when it tries to show you a representation of the array. If you actually look in those indices, it will return `undefined`.