# What's the difference between 'empty x 2' array and [undefined, undefined]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I create the following constant in the browser console:

```
const myArray = Array(2);
```

This outputs the following:

```
(2) [empty × 2]
```

And when I use the spread operator in the following manner:

```
const myUndefinedArray = [...myArray]
```

Then the console returns:

```
(2) [undefined, undefined]
```

In both cases it says the length is two. What are the use cases for each of these options? Is there any specific implication to "empty"?

Comment: Your second one has converted a sparse array into a normal one.  IOW: the second one is going to take memory, the first one doesn't take memory until a element is used.  IOW:  Array elements 0 & 1, actually have a value, and it's value is undefined.

Comment: The first is an empty array with length 2, the second is an array with 2 elements which happen to be the value `undefined`

Comment: @Keith Andreas that's actually not true. Array(2) will create an array with two undefined elements within it. Try it and log it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between empty items in a JavaScrip array and undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326047/whats-the-difference-between-empty-items-in-a-javascrip-array-and-undefined) and [Difference between “empty' and ”undefined" in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936008/)

Comment: @kemicofa  In Chrome it shows like the OP says.

Comment: @Keith, weird. I'm using chrome ( Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) ) and it's showing me double undefined.

Comment: @kemicofa  I'm same version, so it is very strange..  ps.  If you access a sparse array element, it returns undefined.  That's because `empty` is not a Javascript type, it's just how Chrome represents un-allocated sparse array elements.

Comment: @kemicofa _"Array(2) will create an array with two undefined elements within it"_ - No, it doesn't: ECMASCript 2016 -> [22.1.1.2 `Array(len)`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array-len) -> Steps 7 and 8

Answer (score 1):

main difference would be forEach and map properties

`Array(2).map(()=>"value")` will not do anything

`[undefined,undefined].map(()=>"value")` will map

Answer (score 0):

The empty values aren't iterable:

```js
var arr = new Array(5)

arr.forEach(()=> console.log('hello'))

var arr2 = [...arr]

arr2.forEach(()=> console.log('world'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty in an array means the index has never been assigned a value. This has to do with how Javascript deals with arrays. You can try this:

```
var v = new Array();   
v[0]=undefined;
v.length = 2

console.log(v);
```

See, array index 0 has a "property" with name "0", without a value assigned to it (i.e. undefined). The array, however, does not have a property with name "1" at this point. Chrome logs this as "empty" value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArray = Array(2);
console.log(myArray)
```

You're creating here an empty with length 2, that's why you're getting the output of an array with 2x empty values as you didn't put any values inside the created array.

```js
const myArray = Array(2);
const myUndefinedArray = [...myArray]
console.log(myUndefinedArray)
```

You get here `undefined` because you're trying to create an `myUndefinedArray` array using nonexistent values.