# Confusing about removing empty subarrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with a size of 5 and in each element, I fill in with a corresponding subarray, like this:

```js
let equalSums = new Array(5);
    for (let i = 0; i < equalSums.length; i++) {
        equalSums[i] = new Array(5);
}
console.log(equalSums);
/*
[ [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ] ]
*/
```

And after malnipulating to find contigous subarray that equal to a give number (in this case it's 3), I push subarray with sum elements equal 3 to this `equalSum` array, and now it looks like this:

```js
[ [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 2, 1 ],
  [ 3 ] ]
```

The problem is I want to remove all the empty subarrays, then I do the following:

```js
let rs = equalSums.filter(e => e.every(x => x != ""));
console.log(rs);
/* 
[ [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ , , , ,  ],
  [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 2, 1 ],
  [ 3 ] ]
/*
```

Still the same, it doesn't remove the empty subarrays.

But, I use `some` instead, it gives me the desired result:

```js
let rs = equalSums.filter(e => e.some(x => x != ""));
console.log(rs);
/*
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3 ] ]
*/
```

Can anybody explain for me why `every` doesn't work and `some` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sparse `[,,,,]` arrays you have there essentially have *no* elements, only spaces that are occupied by nothing.

So `[,,,,,].every(x => x != '')` asks, "Are all of this array's elements unequal to `""`?" And the answer is Yes. It has no elements, so all of the elements it has (none) are unequal to `""`.

`[,,,,].some(x => x != "")` asks, "Does this array have *any* elements that are unequal to `""`?" And the answer is No. It has no elements, so it doesn't have any that are unequal to `""`.

You haven't really explained why you're using all these sparse arrays, and I suspect you might be going about whatever you're trying to do in the wrong way, but at least this explains what you are seeing with `every` and `some`.

Comment: Looks good to me, I guess this answer explains why some and every have different return values for the same case, it because they are phrasing the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [,,,,] is considered to be an empty array and will behave the same way as [] when using `every` and `some` even tho it says it has a length of 4.
[more info on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936008/difference-between-empty-and-undefined-in-javascript)

`every` and `some` return different values if you call them on an empty array.

```js
[].every(x => x)
true
[].some(x => x)
false
```

Your code seem to rely on this behavior to filter out empty arrays, your check `x != ""` is not what doing the filtering.

Comment: `[[], [], [], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3]]` is not equivalent to what OP has.

Comment: I already use this method, but it didn't work. Each empty string is evaluated to the length of 4.

Comment: @NamV.Do Maybe you should explain what you're actually trying to do here? Why are you filling up your outer array with sparse arrays and then removing them?

Comment: I see, just to be clear does [ , , , ,  ] mean ["", "", "", ""] or [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined] ?

Comment: @YounesElAlami It means neither of those. It means `[,,,,]`

Comment: @JLRishe I see, I've updated the answer to account for that.