# What is empty inside an array? e.g. [empty X 5]

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry for misleading title here, I wasn't able to frame any proper one.

I am confused in array when there is nothing inside them (prints by `empty X n`) but they have length.
e.g. I create array by `const a = [,,,]`. This creates an array whose length is 3 but nothing inside it. If i print it in browser console, it prints the following:

[image]

`What does empty mean here?` If I run map or forEach function and try to console something, I get nothing.

Have added some code.

```js
const a = [,,,]

console.log("print a: ",a)
console.log("print a.length: ",a.length)
console.log("print typeof a[0]: ", typeof a[0])
console.log("a.forEach((data, index) => { console.log(data, index) }): ", a.forEach((data, index) => { console.log(data, index) }))
console.log("")


const b = [undefined, undefined, undefined]

console.log("print b: ", b)
console.log("print b.length: ", b.length)
console.log("print typeof b[0]: ", typeof b[0])
console.log("b.forEach((data, index) => { console.log(data, index) }): ", b.forEach((data, index) => { console.log(data, index) }))
console.log("")

console.log("compare a[0] and b[0]: ", a[0] === b[0])
```

The only thing which differs is when I print a and b (though stackoverflow console prints them same but browser console prints differently) and when I try to loop through the array. Also momentjs isEqual gives them equal ([jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sunil12738/h53sv7gj/4/))

My main doubts are:

- What type of array is it?
- What does empty mean here?
- How is it different from array which has all undefined values or empty array? or is it not?
- Do we use it or any sample use case for this one

I have read about null and undefined array values and have understood it. But for this one, I haven't find anything proper. Most of the search I found were related to const a = [] is an empty array or how to check if array is empty and so on.

So, if someone can explain or give any proper links to read, it will be very helpful.

Please let me know, if I should add anything else.

Comment: Empty is literally that - no data in that slot. It's not `undefined`, nor `null` - the array is sparse.

Comment: Get references from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326047/whats-the-difference-between-empty-items-in-a-javascript-array-and-undefined

Comment: @VLAZ, Please correct me if I am wrong. It is something like: null means memory is allotted with value null (or reference points to null), undefined means memory location is allotted but no value exists (or reference is there but points to nowhere) but `empty means that memory is not even allotted (or reference doesn't exists at all)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between empty items in a JavaScript array and undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326047/whats-the-difference-between-empty-items-in-a-javascript-array-and-undefined)

Comment: @Sunil sort of. Whether memory is allocated or not *in an array* is an implementation detail. An array in JS is not necessarily given contiguous memory like with other languages, so a sparse array can definitely have the empty slots not even taking up space. `null` and `undefined` are both *values*, so they are something that exists. However, it's possible that all bindings that are set to `null` are actually pointing to a single value, so you don't get multiple "copies" of `null`. Not sure if that's done. `undefined` *could* be an actual value or a *lack* of value - e.g. `a = {}; a.foo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Intro to sparse arrays

First a clarification what you've created is called a *sparse array*. To put it simply, sparse arrays are similar to normal arrays but not all of their indexes have data. In some cases, like JavaScript, this leads to slightly more significant handling of them. Other languages simply have a normal array of fixed length with some values that are "zero" in some sense (depends on what value can signify "nothing" for a specific array - might be `0` or `null` or `""`, etc).

## Empty slots

The empty slot in a sparse array is exactly what it sounds like - slot that is not filled with data. JavaScript arrays unlike most other implementations, are not fixed size and can even have some indexes simply *missing*. For example:

```
const arr = [];   // empty array
arr[0] = "hello"; // index 0 filled
arr[2] = "world"; // index 2 filled
```

You will get an array with no index 1. It's not `null`, nor it's empty, it's not there. This is the same behaviour you get when you have an object *without* a property:

```
const person = {foo: "hello"};
```

You have an object with a property `foo` but it doesn't have, for example, a `bar` property. Exactly the same as how the array before doesn't have index `1`.

The only way JavaScript represents a "value not found" is with `undefined`, however that conflates

- "the property exists and the value assigned to it is `undefined`"
- "the property does not exist at all"

Here as an example:

```js
const person1 = { name: "Alice", age: undefined };
const person2 = { name: "Bob" };

console.log("person1.age", person1.age);
console.log("person2.age", person2.age);

console.log("person1.hasOwnProperty('age')", person1.hasOwnProperty('age'));
console.log("person2.hasOwnProperty('age')", person2.hasOwnProperty('age'));
```

You get `undefined` when trying to resolve `age` in either case, however the reasons are different.

Since arrays in JavaScript *are* objects, you get the same behaviour:

```js
const arr = [];   // empty array
arr[0] = "hello"; // index 0 filled
arr[2] = "world"; // index 2 filled

console.log("arr[1]", arr[1]);

console.log("arr.hasOwnProperty(1)", arr.hasOwnProperty(1));
```

## Why it matters

Sparse arrays get a different treatment in JavaScript. Namely, array methods that iterate the collection of items will only go through the *filled* slots and would omit the empty slots. Here is an example:

```js
const sparseArray = [];   // empty array
sparseArray[0] = "hello"; // index 0 filled
sparseArray[2] = "world"; // index 2 filled

const arr1 = sparseArray.map(word => word.toUpperCase());

console.log(arr1); //["HELLO", empty, "WORLD"]


const denseArray = [];     // empty array
denseArray[0] = "hello";   // index 0 filled
denseArray[1] = undefined; // index 1 filled
denseArray[2] = "world";   // index 2 filled

const arr2 = denseArray.map(word => word.toUpperCase()); //error

console.log(arr2);
```

As you can see, iterating a sparse array is fine, but if you have an explicit `undefined`, in the array, then `word => word.toUpperCase()` will fail because `word` is `undefined`.

Sparse arrays are useful if you have numerically indexed data that you want to run `.filter`, `.find`, `.map`, `.forEach` and so on. Let's illustrate again:

```js
//some collection of records indexed by ID
const people = [];
people[17] = { id: 17, name: "Alice", job: "accountant" , hasPet: true  };
people[67] = { id: 67, name: "Bob"  , job: "bank teller", hasPet: false };
people[3] =  { id: 3 , name: "Carol", job: "clerk"      , hasPet: false };
people[31] = { id: 31, name: "Dave" , job: "developer"  , hasPet: true  };


/* some code that fetches records */
const userChoice = 31;
console.log(people[userChoice]);

/* some code that transforms records */
people
  .map(person => `Hi, I am ${person.name} and I am a ${person.job}.`)
  .forEach(introduction => console.log(introduction));
  
/* different code that works with records */
const petOwners = people
  .filter(person => person.hasPet)
  .map(person => person.name);
  
console.log("Current pet owners:", petOwners)
```

Answer (score 0):

its just what it is `empty` its neither `undefined` or `null`
`const a = [,,,,]` is same as `const a = new Array(4)`
here `a` is an array with no elements populated and with only `length` property
do this, `let arr1 = new array()` and then `console.log(arr1.length)` you'll get 0 as output.    and if you do `console.log(arr1)` you'll get `[ <4 empty items> ]`
if you change the length property of arr1 like this `arr1.length = 4` you will have an empty array with it's length property = 4, but no items are populated so those slot will be `empty` and if you do `console.log(typeof(arr1[0])` you get `undefined` only because there is no other possible types to show. And no methods of Array will be applied with an array with empty elements

so,

Empty array means an array with length property and with unpopulated slots

this is different from arrays with `undefined` because in JS `undefined` is a type and you can execute and have results by calling all array methods on it, whereas an array with `empty` elememts have no type and no array methods can be applied on it.