# I'm confused with the behavior of Array.fill() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a nxn chessboard in single line of code using Array.fill like

```
let  board = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill('O'));
```

when i try to modify the first square like board[0][0] = 'Q'.It's changing all the 0th index elements all n sub arrays. My intention is

```
┌─────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ (index) │  0  │  1  │  2  │  3  │
├─────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│    0    │ 'Q' │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │
│    1    │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │
│    2    │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │
│    3    │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │
└─────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

But when i do board[0][0] = 'Q'

```
┌─────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ (index) │  0  │  1  │  2  │  3  │
├─────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│    0    │ 'Q' │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │
│    1    │ 'Q' │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │
│    2    │ 'Q' │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │
│    3    │ 'Q' │ 'O' │ 'O' │ 'O' │
└─────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

But it works as expected, when i'm creating array like this

```
let board = [
  ['O','O','O','O'],
  ['O','O','O','O'],
  ['O','O','O','O'],
  ['O','O','O','O'],
]
```

Comment: fill copies the same reference to all elements.  You will have to map on it

Comment: `Array(n).fill().map(_ => Array(n).fill('O'));` should work. The parameter to `fill` is always aliased.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n = 4
let toFill = 'O'

let board = new Array(n);
for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
    board[i] = ((new Array(n)).fill(toFill))
}

console.log(board);
```

output:

```
[
  [ 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' ],
  [ 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' ],
  [ 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' ],
  [ 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You're filling the single value to the array items

way to do this:

```js
const getGrid = n => Array.from({ length:n }).map(() => new Array(n).fill(0))
```

---

#### Here's why.

While doing `new Array(n)`, it constructs an array whose length is n, and by calling `fill` prototype function and pass an **value**, it just equals to this:

```js
const array = new Array(n);
const someObject = {}; // or [], or new Array(n).fill(0), the same

array[0] = someObject;
array[1] = someObject;
//...
array[n-1] = someObject
```

as all items are pointing to single one object, so while you are modifying the first item, you are operating the `someObject`, and you may see all item changes.
So only way to do this is while filling second-level array to first, you cannot use `fill` function.

#### Another tip

About `Array.from({ length:n })` and `new Array(n)`,by calling `new Array(n)` you are creating an array with all items being `empty`, the array is known as `sparse matrix`, you cannot use `.map(()=>{})` to fill it. but `Array.from({length:n})` will create an array with `undefined` as items, which can be mapped to other values.

#### You may want these as reference:

[is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

[javascript-primitive-vs-reference-values](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-primitive-vs-reference-values/)

[whats-the-difference-between-empty-items-in-a-javascript-array-and-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326047/whats-the-difference-between-empty-items-in-a-javascript-array-and-undefined)