# Empty slots are made non-empty after reversing an array

Tags: javascript

As the question states I have an array which may or may not contain empty elements. I want to reverse this array. After using the `reverse` operation all the empty elements are made non-empty and thus, can be iterated. Why is this even allowed and how can I preserve the elements in the reversed array?

```js
const originalArray = new Array(5);
originalArray[2] = "a";
originalArray.push("b");
originalArray.push("c");

const reversedArray = Array.from(originalArray).reverse();

console.log('');
console.log('original');
originalArray.forEach((el, index) => console.log('el: ', el, ' index: ', index));

console.log('');
console.log('reversed');
reversedArray.forEach((el, index) => console.log('el: ', el, ' index: ', index));

/*

Output is as follows:
original:
el:  a  index:  2
el:  b  index:  5
el:  c  index:  6

reversed:
el:  c  index:  0
el:  b  index:  1
el:  undefined  index:  2
el:  undefined  index:  3
el:  a  index:  4
el:  undefined  index:  5
el:  undefined  index:  6

I would have expected that there are still empty elements in the reversed array.

*/
```

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326047/whats-the-difference-between-empty-items-in-a-javascript-array-and-undefined) answer your question?

Comment: In short, the problem is not `reverse()`, the step you want to investigate is `Array.from()`. To see what I mean, check the output of your snippet without calling `reverse()`.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @Etheryte this does not solve my problem.

Comment: @NinaScholz I just added :)

Comment: As @Etheryte alludes to, and [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) state early and explicitly, "`Array.from()` never creates a sparse array. If the `arrayLike` object is missing some index properties, they become `undefined` in the new array."

Comment: And for `slice()`: "The `slice()` method preserves empty slots. If the sliced portion is sparse, the returned array is sparse as well."

Answer (score 3):

#### Use `.slice()`

Replace

```
const reversedArray = Array.from(originalArray).reverse();
```

with

```
const reversedArray = originalArray.slice().reverse();
```

This will create a new array which retains the curious "gappiness" of your original array, but in the reverse pattern of course.

Comment: While this offers a solution, it doesn't explain the nature of the problem nor why the original code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: "Why is this even allowed and _how can I preserve the elements in the reversed array_?"

I can't answer the philosophical question, but at least I gave the solution you specifically asked for. 8-)

Answer (score 0):

Various ways to create shallow/deep copies of array work differently

```
const originalArray = new Array(5);
originalArray[2] = "a";
originalArray.push("b");
originalArray.push("c");

Array.from(originalArray)
//> [undefined, undefined, 'a', undefined, undefined, 'b', 'c']

[...originalArray]
//> [undefined, undefined, 'a', undefined, undefined, 'b', 'c']

originalArray.slice()
//> [empty × 2, 'a', empty × 2, 'b', 'c']

originalArray.map(v => v)
//> [empty × 2, 'a', empty × 2, 'b', 'c']

originalArray.filter(() => true)
//> ['a', 'b', 'c']

originalArray.concat()
//> [empty × 2, 'a', empty × 2, 'b', 'c']

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalArray))
//> [null, null, 'a', null, null, 'b', 'c']
```

This is due to the way each method treats the passed object, for instance as an array or an iterable. You could use the ones which preserve the sparse array as-is.

Answer (score 0):

As @Eureka said, you can use the `slice()` method instead of `Array.from()`:

```js
const reversedArray = originalArray.slice().reverse();
```

This will retain the sparseness of the array.

---

The output you are seeing is because of the behavior of `Array.from()` when dealing with sparse arrays.
From the description in [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

> `Array.from()` never creates a sparse array. If the `arrayLike` object is missing some index properties, they become `undefined` in the new array.

Using `Array.prototype.slice()` gives the output you want, as its behavior is different:

> The `slice()` method preserves empty slots. If the sliced portion is sparse, the returned array is sparse as well. ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice))

This difference in behavior is because of the semantic and functional difference between `from()` and `slice()`: `Array.from()` creates a new array *from* iterable objects and array-like objects, while the `slice()` method *copies* a portion of an array into a new array.

More specifically, `slice()` reads the properties in the specified range, and copies those to a new array:

> The `slice()` method reads the `length` property of `this`. It then reads the integer-keyed properties from `start` to `end` and defines them on a newly created array.

`Array.from()`, on the other hand, works something like this when given an array-like object (an object with the `length` property and indexed elements):

1. Read the normalized `length` of the array-like object.
2. Construct a new array object, passing in the length to the constructor.
3. For every index up to the length, set that index in the new array object to the value of that index in the original array-like object. Any empty slots will give `undefined`, and thus be non-empty in the new array.
4. Run the map function on the new array, if one is passed.

(The `Array.from()` explanation is my understanding based on the docs and experience, but should give the gist of it.)