# Index of elisions in JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, elision

What is the difference between the `undefined` elements in JavaScript arrays:

1. created directly,
2. created with elision?

Elements of case 1. and 2. both have `undefined` types and values, but **the ones born in elision don't have indexes** (or any enumerable properties, their array has a correct `Array.length` that's clear). Can you give some background on this?

**Example:**

```js
// case 1.
const undefineds = [undefined, undefined, undefined].map((el, i) => i)
console.log(undefineds, undefineds.length, 'undefineds')

// case 2.
const empties = [,,,].map((el, i) => i)
console.log(empties, empties.length, 'empties')
```

**Output:**

```
Array [0, 1, 2] 3 "undefineds"
Array [undefined, undefined, undefined] 3 "empties"
```

*Note:* In case 2. I am aware of not just the indexes `i` would be undefined, but anything returned from the iteration, e.g.: `[,,,].map((el, i) => 'puppies')` => `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

Comment: It seems like you already know the difference. What "background" are you asking for exactly?

Comment: Notice that when you `map` over an array with elisions, the point is that the callback doesn't get called at all on the non-existing elements. It's not like it's called with `undefined` for the value and `undefined` for the index. Also, it does not return an array of `undefined`s, it does return another sparse array - your `console.log` implementation appears to be confused by that though. It should log `[,,,]` or `[empty, empty, empty]` or [something like that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10683773/1048572).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description

Comment: @Bergi thank you, your comment and the three duplicates linked are exactly what I needed as background of this phenomenon.

Comment: @epascarello thanks, super relevant! I should have started with `Array.map`'s docs it seems.